# How do you say "Three strikes, you're out!" in German?

Tags: translation

I've looked this up on LEO.de and Google, and haven't found a suitable answer. How do you express the concept of

> Three strikes, you're out!

in German? Has it just been "absorbed" into the language as "Three Strikes," or is there an alternate way of saying this?

I am looking both for everyday expressions, as well as a baseball-specific translation, if there's a difference between the two.

Comment: Are you looking for a baseball-related translation or for an everyday phrase that would express the same thing?

Comment: If you're looking for an everyday phrase, an example would be helpful.

Comment: Both. Edited to clarify.

Comment: [Drei Verstöße, du bist draußen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_strikes). Aber ich bezweifel, dass man das ernsthaft ingame so sagt. Auf der WP-Seite wird auch Urheberrecht und Strafrecht kurz thematisiert.

Comment: Can you explain what this phrase means? For me it sounds like it was related to baseball, but nobody in Europe knows this sport. Well, we often see it in movies and TV-series that are produced in the USA, but it is not played here in Europe (with some very rare exceptions), and almost nobody here knows the rules. It is not part of our culture.

Comment: It’s baseball lingo. When a pitcher successfully throws three strikes that the batter can’t hit, the batter is “out” and it becomes the next batter’s turn. It’s also used in a criminal context: criminals who get three convictions (“three strikes”) face much tougher criminal penalties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Beim dritten Mal bist Du draußen.

Häufiger sind Regeln, bei denen man beim zweiten Mal draußen ist.

Man kennt noch den recht sinnlosen Begriff

> Aller guten Dinge sind Drei.

den man beispielsweise verwendet, wenn man die gleiche Person am selben Tag 3x trifft, oder auch ironisch, wenn einem 3x ein Gegenstand runterfällt.

> Drei Mal ist Bremer Recht.

habe ich auch schon gehört, aber was hier gemeint ist habe ich wieder vergessen. Es wird auch für alles mögliche gebraucht, was 3x vorkommt.

> Du hast 3 Versuche

ist eine häufige Regel bei Spielen - häufiger als 4 Versuche, aber ob häufiger als 2 müsste mal jemand untersuchen. Im Recht (Abmahnungen, Unterlassungserklärungen) gilt meist der erste Fall als weniger dramatisch, aber beim zweiten Mal wird es ernst.

> Es gibt nur einen Warnschuss.

Comment: "'Drei Mal ist Bremer Recht': Als Bremer kann man sich nach zwei misslungenen Versuchen an irgendwas immer herrlich rausreden mit 'Dreimal ist Bremer Recht', aber es heißt auch, das die liberalen Bremer jedwedem drei Mal eine Chance einräumen." http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremensien

Answer (score 15):

user unknown gave some good examples for expressing *a similar thing* like `Three strikes, you're out`.

But I'd say, since the expression is clearly related to Baseball, which again is an American sport, there is no translation in German. Either you'd use the word `strike` as it or express it completely different.

Comment: This is the only appropriate answer. Baseball may be the national sport of the U.S., but it's the least understood and appreciated of the big four team sports in Europe. Baseball metaphors are simply completely opaque to Germans.

Comment: This. The metaphor behind the sentence is US-specific and even if translated properly won't make sense to most Germans.

Answer (score 1):

Another variant is using *Warnschuss* for *strike*. Other possible translations are *Mahnungen* or just *Verwarnungen*.